Facing issue in fetching child product attributes value
I have following code, In which I am fetching attribute values for child and parent products:
 public function setAttributeValues(array $products)
    {
        $this->values = [];
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                if (empty($value)) {
                    $value = $product->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
                }
                $this->setValue($attribute->getId(), $product->getId(), $value);
            }

            if ($product->getTypeID() == Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                $children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $childAttributes = $child->getAttributes();

                    foreach ($childAttributes as $childAttribute) {
                        $value = $childAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($child);
                        print_r($value); // Facing attribute issue here
                        $this->setValue($childAttribute->getId(), $child->getId(), $value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

I am getting null values for some attributes. In if ($product->getTypeID() == Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {} part. I've tried multiple logic to fetch attribute value but none of them worked for me. Also, I've verified that attribute value are set for the the particular product.
Any help would be really appreciated.

your issue is the product attribute configuration
Those whose values is not printing you have to go to product attributes
open the attribute
and select YES in "Used in Product Listing"
Please don't forget to clear cache after changing value of attribute
That will solve your issue


Hey, thank you for the answer.

@smit kandiya
Hey,
You can use a collection to fetch the attributes of child products
use
Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

protected $productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

public function getChildProductAttributes($configurableProduct)
{
    $childIds = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($configurableProduct->getId());
    $childIds = array_shift($childIds);

    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_code')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $childIds]);

    foreach ($collection as $childProduct) {
        $attributeValue = $childProduct->getData('attribute_code');
        // Process attribute value
    }
}

Thank You!

Hey, Thank you for the answer.
